# Best way to use/learn ML for board-game reinforcement learning

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, python

I am relatively new to Python but I taught myself enough to code a two-player board game that is similar to chess. It has a simple Tkinter UI. Now I am dipping into machine learning, and I want to write another program to play itself in this game repeatedly and "naturally" learn strategies for playing the game.

Can anyone give advice on what I might be able to use for this? Is Tensorflow a good option? Is there a Python library well suited for this that I could adapt and train? I am partially through the [buildingai.elementsofai.com](https://buildingai.elementsofai.com/) course, but I am still very new at ML / AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a 2-player game it goes a little deeper into RL if you want both sides to be RL algorithms. I recommend reading about game theory and what is a Nash Equilibrium to start. For algorithms [hiivemdptoolbox](https://github.com/hiive/hiivemdptoolbox) has [openai-gym](https://gym.openai.com/) compatibility as well as Q-Learning. You will need to add code to make 2 learners play each other. I would also recommend adding Dyna-Q to the Q-Learner as it will probably speed up the learning.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about leveraging learning from both sides. I guess I couldn't have the same learner play both sides and split the data on the go?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches - the initial one would be a rule based one with some amount of randomness. The ML-AI approach is some variation of [reinforcement learning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning), defining your game as an environment, see for instance [openai-gym](https://gym.openai.com). ”Some variation” might be Deep Q Learning or [A3C](https://medium.com/sciforce/reinforcement-learning-and-asynchronous-actor-critic-agent-a3c-algorithm-explained-f0f3146a14ab).